# Jython: getDeclaredMethod double type parameter error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection, double, jython, jython-2.7

I'm working with Jython. I'm trying to call a method inside a Java class using getDeclaredMethod.

My problem is that the method I want to call has one parameter of type double and this type does not exist in Jython. So, if I call the method with java.lang.Double type, it throws me the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException, because Double is different than double.

For example, my method is the following:

```
public void calculateDate(double value, Date startdate)
```

And I'm trying to use the following code to call the method:

```
classesParameters = [Double, Date]
calculateDateMethod = javaobject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("calculateDate", classesParameters)
calculateDateMethod.setAccessible(True)
    
objects = [24.33, startDate]
dateCalculation = calculateDateMethod.invoke(javaobject, objects)
```

How can I get around this?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Float" instead.  That's what jython uses for the double implementation.